# adding $ANDROID_HOME/tools to $Path in windows

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-sdk-tools

I'm trying to run this code:

```
cd google-play-services_lib
android update project -p .
ant debug
```

from this [tutorial](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/MapsAndLocationDemo_v2#prequisites). I installed `ant` using [winant](http://code.google.com/p/winant/), but regarding Android, I can not add this to path.

I tried adding the variable like this screen shot, but it did not help me. How can I add this?

[image]

I'm not sure what is the relation between `android` command and the `android_home/tools` folder. I can not find any `android.exe` file in the `android_home/tools` folder. Maybe I should try another solution to run this.

**EDIT**
When I change the variable base on Tom's reply now the result is:
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$ANDROID_HOME` is an environment variable that is the directory you have your Android SDK installed in - it's not any specific directory. You don't have to create an environment variable for it (although it does make scripting things easier later on).

So in your example, just add the directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools` to your `PATH`.

*UPDATE* : Hmmm, you don't have the XCOPY command in your path?  That is bizarre. Typically `xcopy.exe` is found in `C:\Windows\System32`. Check your `PATH` statement and see if that directory is contained within.

Comment: Thanks,Now, android is known but new issue. please see the edit.

Comment: My tools directory was located at:  C:\Users\ExampleUsername\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools